# Hard Reset and Factory Reset is not working anymore

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset

When I am trying to do factory reset, my phone only restart. And I cant perform Hard reset because if I want to go to recovery mode, it will restart only. I seems like the recovery mode is destroyed. Is there any solution in this problem? .

phone specs(According to CPU-Z)

;ChinaPhone

:Hardware: MT6572

:Android 4.4.2

:Root Access: Yes

. ->recently, I can perform this two methods and I can Access recovery mode(power+volume up), but suddenly it goes like that. PLS HELP!!

Comment: What do you mean by *"I cant perform Hard reset because if I want to go to recovery mode, it will restart only"* ? What happens when you try to go to recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

although I'm not sure but try pressing the power button the home button and the volume down at the same time after you've turned off your cellphone and then use the volume up and down keys to select factory reset but you have to remember the gmail synced to your device and the password to be able to re-use it

Comment: I have no home button, and If I try to pres volume down and power at the same time ,it will go to the test mode

Comment: The OP has tried what you said already. You refer to recovery mode, which the OP says that he cannot access. Please edit your answer to make it more appropriate.